# Is it possible to map a whole table to an object?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Is it possible to map a whole table to a .Net object, as opposed to only individual rows? Basically like a DataTable, complete with table name, column structure, table properties, etc.

Comment: Why not use a [strongly-typed DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163877.aspx)?  What does it lack that you want?

Comment: @DStanley It's for work, and we use NH to do all DB connections. So what it lacks is: being NHibernate.

Answer (score 1):

A DataTable is a whole table mapped to an object.

If you don't want to have a container of rows then I guess you could have a 2-D array of 'objects' and lose your strong typing, or if everything is a single type you could use that (string maybe?).  If you want strongly typed different columns you could have an array for each column with all of the values in a particular row, basically inverting the datatable to have a collection of columns with the data rather than a collection or rows.

My guess is that you're going about this the wrong way though; you either want a DataTable, or a single object representing one row and then having a collection (List/Dictionary/whatever) of those objects.